Argument of a function and return statement
import java.util.*;
class Main{
    public static int  factorial(int a){
      int fac=1;
       for(int i=1;i<=a;i++){
            fac=fac*i;
            
    }
    return fac;
    }
    public static void main( String[] args){
       Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
       int a = sc.nextInt();
       
       System.out.print(fac);
    }
        
 }

System.out.print(fac);
                        ^
  symbol:   variable fac
location: class Main
1 error

This was the error shown , my question is if we have declared the variable <sum >in the function and it  stores the updated values during the loop then why we are required to  define a new variable to store the value of the factorial !!
import java.util.*;
class Main{
    public static int  factorial(int a){
        int fac=1;
       for(int i=1;i<=a;i++){
            fac=fac*i;
            
    }
    return fac;
    }
    public static void main( String[] args){
       Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
       int a = sc.nextInt();
       int sum =factorial(a);
       System.out.print(sum);
    }
        
 }
    

this was the solution shown , why we need to store the value in function name<factorial>instead of fac ?


Because in order to store the result of a method you need to (1) call the method and (2) assign its result to something (in this case a single variable).  A local variable only exists within the method in which it's declared, and even if that weren't the case the first example never even called the method anyway.

Does this answer your question? What is 'scope' in Java?

Note that this is no different from any of the other variables you use.  For example: int a = sc.nextInt();  Following your same logic... If you're asserting that sc.nextInt() already internally has its result then why do you declare a variable called a to store that result?  Well, because otherwise how would you use that result in your code?

The reason we need to store the value in the function name is to make the result of the calculation available to the code that calls the function. In this case the main function calls the factorial function and stores the returned value in the variable sum. Thus this allows the main function to use the result of the calculation in subsequent code eg: printing the result to the console.
